# I have html form and need to make it work in text editor on template. Only problem is it has .sccs styling file

Tags: css, forms, html

I have html form and need to make it work in text editor on template. Only problem is it has .sccs styling file because there is adjectance combinator. Code is in https://codepen.io/fede19/pen/zYZMbXB.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking... Adjacent Sibling Combinators exist in the native CSS specification - you don't need SCSS to use them. SCSS has to be compiled to be used in any browser - it's no different here. The WordPress runtime does not include facilities for SCSS compilation - you'd need to compile the SCSS to CSS beforehand in any scenario, then just enqueue the CSS per usual

Comment: In Codepen you can just click on the down arrow to compile SCSS to CSS. Looking at your question I believe that's all you need?